# Paste multi-line snippets into IPython

Tags: python, ipython, multiline, paste

I used IPython in the past and I used to be able to copy and paste multi-line commands, e.g., a `for` loop in IPython.

Working on my new PC after installing Python(x,y) 2.7.2.1, I can paste multi-line snippets by using right-click → *Edit* → *Paste*, but not by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, as I used to do.

When using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, only the first line for the multi-line snippet gets pasted. How can I fix this?

I looked in the settings and documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 25):

Type %paste into the IPython command line.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `%cpaste` with IPython shell (which is also what is used by Django's management shell). If you want to learn more of the features, type `%quickref`.