# Get Input in Python Interactive Mode

Tags: python, python-interactive

Say I have a simple script that depends on my input:

```py
w = input()
print(f'Input is {w}')
```

If I copy and paste this script (both lines at the same time) into the interactive window, it won't pause on `input` line to receive an input.

```
>>> w = input()
print(f'Input is {w}')
>>>
```

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Update:
This seems to work just fine on Pycharm:

```
In: w = input()
print(f'Input is {w}')
>? test
Input is test
```

Comment: Why do you need to paste this into the interactive window in the first place? Why not just write it into a .py file and execute the file?

Comment: I just want to select the lines I want to test and run those instead of executing the whole file.

Comment: Well, in that case as a hacky workaround you can wrap them in an `if True:` block - the REPL won't evaluate an indented block until it's over (plus one newline).

Comment: Ah interesting! Thank you!

Comment: Why not paste one line at a time? Python's interactive mode is generally meant to be used one statement at a time.

Comment: right that is one solution, though that's a bit inconvenient to do it with multiple inputs in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [IPython](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which supports pasting blocks:

```
In [1]: w = input()
   ...: print(f'Input is {w}')
a
Input is a
```

Just in case that doesn't work, you could use the command `%paste` to load and execute the clipboard contents, or `%cpaste` so that you can paste manually:

```
In [2]: %paste
w = input()
print(f'Input is {w}')

## -- End pasted text --
b
Input is b

In [4]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:w = input()
:print(f'Input is {w}')
:--
ERROR! Session/line number was not unique in database. History logging moved to new session 1903
c
Input is c
```

(I'm not sure what this error means BTW, though I notice the "In" number ticked up once more than it should have.)

See also: [Paste Multi-line Snippets into IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10230820/4518341)

Comment: Tested on IPython and it works! I added `"python.terminal.launchArgs": ["-m", "IPython", "--no-autoindent"]` to my VSCode setting.